# How to cut an image into 2 using SwiftUI

Tags: image, swiftui, uiimage, crop, geometryreader

I have an image like this [image]

I'd like to split it into 2 pieces across the center using SwiftUI. Leaving me with 2 separate images that I can access. However I can't figure out how to split the original into a top and bottom piece. The two pieces must line up to create the original image.

Top Image:
[image]

Bottom Image:
[image]

I've tried use a geometry reader to read the height and width and return an image with half the height, but the two images don't like up like this.

```
GeometryReader { geo in
    image
       .frame(width: geo.width, height: geo.height / 2, alignment: .center)
       .clipped()
}
```

Comment: Do you want to split it visually (ie. only on screen) or physically (ie on two separated half-height images)?

Comment: @Asperi physically, so I have 2 separate images that I can put back together later (weird I know).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here a way of doing this: with using `clipped()` modifier.

---

[image]

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var spacing: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    @State private var imageSize: CGSize = CGSize()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let image = Image(systemName: "star")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .cornerRadius(10.0)
            .background(GeometryReader { proxy in Color.clear.onAppear() { imageSize = proxy.size } })
        
        
        return ZStack {
            
            VStack(spacing: spacing) {
                
                image.frame(width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height/2, alignment: .top).clipped()
                
                image.frame(width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height/2, alignment: .bottom).clipped()
            }
            
            VStack { Spacer(); Slider(value: $spacing,in: 0.0...100.0) }
            
        }
        .padding()
        .compositingGroup()
        .shadow(radius: 10.0)
        
    }
}
```